# How to create login function register on firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

currently i am making a website but i want 3 pages. One for the user one for the poster and one for the admin. But Firebase authentication can only be used to login for users. I want to manually login via firestore but don't know how yet. Hope anyone can show me how to login to the subscription by saving data to firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't have any way to perform user sign-in.  That's what Firebase Authentication is for.  It's unclear from your question why you can't use Firebase Auth, but I suspect you're designing your application in a way that's highly unusual.  I suggest rethinking your design.